# Fill height of a div over 100%

Tags: html, css

I'm trying this code:

The HTML:

```
<div id="cnt">
  <div id="left">
  I'm left
  </div>

  <div id="right">
  I'm right
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
html,body,#cnt{
  height:100%;
}
#left {
  background: #990000;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
}

#right {
  margine-left: 100px;
  background: #009900;
}
```

The question: How do I make `left` DIV to stretch in height as the `right` DIV stretches?

Consider the `<br>`s as dynamic content, that may grow, for example.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `flex` on the parent, then `flex-grow: 1` on the right side so it fills the available space. By default, the left/right columns in this flex row will be the same height.

(btw, you misspelled `margin-right` on `#right`)

```css
body {margin:0;}
#cnt {
  /* use min-height if you want the content to be at least the window height;
  /* min-height: 100vh; */
  display: flex;
}
#cnt {
  display: flex;
}
#left {
  background: #990000;
}

#right {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: #009900;
}
```

```html
<div id="cnt">
  <div id="left">
  I'm left
  </div>

  <div id="right">
  I'm right
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, this isn't working... the color isn't filled, don't you see?

Comment: @mizzo it's your use of `height` and you left the `float` stuff on `#left` https://jsfiddle.net/2v3ayywx/2/